# Craft 3 - custom callback after Garnish onDragStop

Tags: plugin-development, matrix, craft3, javascript, garnish

I would like to trigger a custom javascript function after an element in a matrix block was moved in the matrix but I'm not sure how to attach the event without changing the `MatrixInput.js`.

So far I've tried the easy way with attaching element handler in my plugins `init()` function

```
Garnish.$doc.on('dragStop', '.matrixblock > .actions > .move', this.onMoveEnd.bind(this))
```

But of course that did not work. The `Craft.MatrixInput` contains a the function

```
this.blockSort = new Garnish.DragSort($blocks, {
    handle: '> .actions > .move',
    axis: 'y',
    filter: $.proxy(function() {
        // Only return all the selected items if the target item is selected
        if (this.blockSort.$targetItem.hasClass('sel')) {
            return this.blockSelect.getSelectedItems();
        }
        else {
            return this.blockSort.$targetItem;
        }
    }, this),
    collapseDraggees: true,
    magnetStrength: 4,
    helperLagBase: 1.5,
    helperOpacity: 0.9,
    onSortChange: $.proxy(function() {
        this.blockSelect.resetItemOrder();
    }, this)
});
```

Can anyone please tell me how to extend this without breaking Craft updates?

Accessing this event with `Craft.MatrixInput.blockSort` to attach something does not work either and I'm not sure how I can make use of the `this.trigger('dragStop');` [event](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/garnishjs/blob/develop/src/BaseDrag.js#L256).

I've tried to dig into [Garnish events](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/garnishjs/blob/develop/src/Garnish.js#L563) to attach the handlers, but I'm not sure how. `Garnish.on` does not work, `Garnish.Drag.on` either, `Garnish.Base` returns a function but `Garnish.Base()` returns undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Garnish’s Base class introduces its own concept of events, that is separate from DOM events.

Here’s how you’d set up the listener:

```javascript
// get the Craft.MatrixInput object
var matrix = $('.matrix-field').data('matrix');

// attach a handler to its block sorter's sortChange event
matrix.blockSort.on('sortChange', function() {
    // event handler...
});
```